# Why is my overloaded assignment operator is not being invoked on initialization?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, double-free

I created a test class to demonstrate the use of the overloaded assignment operator, and the pitfalls associated with double freeing memory. The code for this class is below:

```
class Test {
  public:
    Test() : ptr{new int(0)}, val{0}, id{count++} {}

    Test(int ptr_val, int new_val) : ptr{new int(ptr_val)}, val{new_val}, id{count++} {}

    ~Test()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }

    Test& operator=(const Test& rhs)
    {
        *ptr = *(rhs.ptr);
        val = rhs.val;
    }

    void setPtrVal(int ptr_val)
    {
        *ptr = ptr_val;
    }

    void setVal(int new_val)
    {
        val = new_val;
    }

    void printData() const
    {
        cout << "id  = " << id  << endl;
        cout << "val = " << val << endl;
        cout << "ptr = " << ptr << endl;
        cout << "*ptr = " << *ptr << endl << endl;
    }
  private:
    int* ptr;
    int val;
    int id;

    static int count;
};

int Test::count = 1;
```

And I am having two main functions which are testing this class with the overloaded assignment operator. I am putting the output for each main function directly below it's body.

Main 1:

```
int main()
{
    Test t1;
    Test t2(2, 2);

    t1.printData();
    t2.printData();

    t2 = t1;  // Overloaded Assignment Operator
    t1.printData();
    t2.printData();

    t2.setVal(3);
    t2.setPtrVal(3);

    t1.printData();
    t2.printData();

    return 0;
}
```

Output 1: (works as expected)

```
id  = 1
val = 0
ptr = 0x204dc20
*ptr = 0

id  = 2
val = 2
ptr = 0x204dc40
*ptr = 2

id  = 1
val = 0
ptr = 0x204dc20
*ptr = 0

id  = 2
val = 0
ptr = 0x204dc40
*ptr = 0

id  = 1
val = 0
ptr = 0x204dc20
*ptr = 0

id  = 2
val = 3
ptr = 0x204dc40
*ptr = 3
```

Main 2:

```
int main()
{
    Test t1(10, 15);

    {
        Test t2 = t1;
        t2.printData();
    }

    t1.printData();

    return 0;
}
```

Output 2 (does not work as expected):

```
id  = 1
val = 15
ptr = 0xd6fc20
*ptr = 10

id  = 1
val = 15
ptr = 0xd6fc20
*ptr = 0

*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000d6fc20 ***
```

This is weird. For some reason, the pointer points to the same memory, and the `id` field is the same. It should be different. It appears that the default assignment operator is invoked. I don't know why this is the case.

Don't try to criticize the program itself. This is just a test for educational purposes. I set this up on purpose so that I would have a double free bug. The overloaded assignment operator is meant to prevent that. And it fails the second test... Why it does that?

Comment: `Test t2 = t1;` is not an assignment. It's copy construction equal to `Test t2(t1);` You did not provide `Test(const Test&)`, so compiler generates one for you. Unforunately, compiler-generated special members are not suited to correctly handle deep copying

Comment: Assignment is not initialisation.

Comment: ... And the haters just keep coming.

Answer (score -4):

It is because initialization is not the same as assignment. So the overloaded assignment operator is not being called. The copy constructor is being called in Main 2. And because this `class Test` does not define an overloaded copy constructor, the default copy constructor is used, which does a member-by-member copy.

I'll demonstrate it by adding a copy constructor:

```
class Test {
  public:
    Test() : ptr{new int(0)}, val{0}, id{count++} {}

    Test(int ptr_val, int new_val) : ptr{new int(ptr_val)}, val{new_val}, id{count++} {}

    ~Test()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }

    Test(const Test& rhs) : ptr{new int( *(rhs.ptr)  )}, val{rhs.val}, id{count++}
    {
        cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
    }

    Test& operator=(const Test& rhs)
    {
        *ptr = *(rhs.ptr);
        val = rhs.val;
    }

    void setPtrVal(int ptr_val)
    {
        *ptr = ptr_val;
    }

    void setVal(int new_val)
    {
        val = new_val;
    }

    void printData() const
    {
        cout << "id  = " << id  << endl;
        cout << "val = " << val << endl;
        cout << "ptr = " << ptr << endl;
        cout << "*ptr = " << *ptr << endl << endl;
    }
  private:
    int* ptr;
    int val;
    int id;

    static int count;
};

int Test::count = 1;


int main()
{
    Test t1(10, 15);

    {
        Test t2 = t1;
        t2.printData();
    }

    t1.printData();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
copy constructor called
id  = 2
val = 15
ptr = 0xea4c40
*ptr = 10

id  = 1
val = 15
ptr = 0xea4c20
*ptr = 10
```

Comment: The copy constructor (and assignment) does a member by member copy, not bit by bit.